# Life contingencies problem - Probability of dying at age $60$

Tags: probability

I'm practicing at this kind of mathematics (life contingencies), and I cannot understand something:

**"Determine the probability that a person, aged $55$, is dead in his $60^{\text{th}}$ year ?"**

The answer that was given (homework):

Result = (number of people dead **at $59$**)/(number of people at $55$).

I cannot figure out why it should be nb of people dead **at $59$**, and not the number of people dead **at $60$**

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first year is the interval $(0,1)$. Similarly, your $60$th year is the interval $(59,60)$. In other words, the interval containing ages such as $59.1, 59.2,..., 59.9$. Thus, we need the number of people dying at age $59$.

Comment: Thanks very much Brady. This is now clear. Simple and powerful explanation. I'll validate your answer. Thanks to Alex too.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to look at this in the following way: if there are $n$ 55yo people now, there will be $k$ of them (60yo) in 5 years, and clearly $k<n$, hence the probability of survivial is $\frac{k}{n}$, i.e. the probability to die in this period is $p=1-\frac{k}{n}$.

EDIT: another way of looking at it is using Geometric probability. Say, the probability for a person who just turned 55 to die *every* year is $p$. Hence the probability he dies within 365 days of his $60^{th}$ anniversary is just 
$$
\mathbf{P}=(1-p)^5p
$$
Here $(1-p)^5$ reflects the fact he doesn't die when he is 55-59, and dies exactly within 365-day range between his $60^{th}$ and the day before $61^{st}$ birthdays.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I agree, but in fact, the homework says, the probability that the person will die exactly in his 60 year, not before his 60 anniversary. Do you have any idea?